# Try in python, repeat if error but not inside a loop?

Tags: python, error-handling

So I have a function I want to run, however this function connects to a serial device, if the device was not turned off correctly it will return an error if you try to run such a function. Since I only need to run the function once all I want is to

```
try
   #function
except
   #function to turn off the device
   #try again
```

not within a loop since I want to just run it once and keep going, is this possible in python without using a loop?

Comment: Could you write a function to check if the connection work and run it before you try to run your current function?

Comment: Why not within a loop? Do you only want to try twice maximum?

Comment: There is, but the function will work to check the connection, since the device is alive, but when you try to poll data from the device it will give a byte mismatch, the only fix is to restart the device and try again.

Comment: I guess what's confusing is that you say you only want to run it once, but there is this "try again" comment. Which is it?

Comment: May be your need to use multiprocessing? Loop from parallel process...

Comment: Replace `#try again` with `#function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, since you explicitly want to use this logic maximum twice and be exception safe, just wrap everything into a function which returns the success status and call it twice:

```
def connect_and_do_stuff_safe() -> bool:
    try
       # function
       return True
    except
       # function to turn off the device
       return False

if not connect_and_do_stuff_safe():
    # Maybe you need to do some start related logic in between, anyway you need it here
    connect_and_do_stuff_safe()
```